# Magento 2 - How to add custom css files into the head?

Tags: magento2, layout, xml

> In Magento 1.x, I can add the CSS files into the head using the helper
>   like below code.

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addCss"><stylesheet helper="module/helperclass/helperfunction"/></action>
</reference>
```

> Anyone know how to do this in Magento 2?

Comment: did you got this sorted out ? or do you have any alternate on this. let me know if you find out some

Comment: sorry, I have no solution yet. now, I added this code <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php echo $_helper->getCSSFile()?>"> into "after.body.start" container.

Comment: I found the solution, please check below answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need helper, you can using this code below in your layout:

```
<head>
    <css src="Namespace_YourModule::css/styles.css"/>
</head>
```

Comment: Because I need to add dynamic css file.

Comment: Can you please provide the src example for contact module if i want to add style.css file in the page with the contact form ? I tried <css src="Magento_Contact::css/styles.css"/> but it didn't work... I am missing the flow of magento includes apparently. The styles.css file is in the module-contact/view/css/ folder...

Comment: Hello @LachezarRaychev, if your handle in frontend, you need create `styles.css` file in `../view/frontend/css/style.css`. With backend, you need create `styles.css` file in `../view/adminhtml/css/style.css`.

Comment: tried that and put #contact-form{  border:1px solid blue !important; } did not work... file is in view/frontend/css/styles.css  and  <css src="Magento_Contact::css/styles.css"/> is in contact_index_index.xml in the <head></head> element .... no blue border around the form... really weird..

Comment: Nvm... i had to create the folder Magento_Contact in static/frontend/Magento/luma/sv_SE and inside create the css/ folder and inside put the styles.css file... now it works. I just thought that that way it would import the file form inside the module-contact/view/frontend/css/ folder...

Comment: Yes, I think it can need permission create `.css` file in `pub/static` folder. You should view page source to check this `.css` file added to `<your_host>/contact/index/index` page.

Comment: @Bill what if module/helperclass/helperfunction the function generates a dynamic css file.

Answer (score 9):

I found the solution myself.

In Layout xml file.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="head.additional">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="block_name" template="custom_head.phtml" />
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

In custom_head.phtml file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php echo $_helper->getCSSFile()?>">
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this steps.

1. Create css file under this directory.
   **app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/web/css/customcss.css**
2. Create **default_head_blocks.xml** file if not exist at this path
   **app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml**

Put below code in **default_head_blocks.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
        <css src="css/customcss.css" />
    </head>
</page>
```

Hope this helps you!!

Comment: Do I need to run any grunt commands after doing this?

Comment: the css file name is dynamic. now, I added this code <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php echo $_helper->getCSSFile()?>"> into "after.body.start" container, how can I add this code into <head>?

Answer (score 1):

Create custom model

add xml file **Namespace/YourModule/view/frontend/layout/default_head_blocks.xml**

this file will change head layout using page configuration 
read more on http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-types.html#layout-types-conf

file content example

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Namespace_YourModule::css/custom.css" />
    </head>
</page>
```

then add css file on this path
**Namespace/YourModule/view/frontend/web/css/custom.css**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked for me. Now css is applied in all pages using this file.

Comment: Can you help me, how I can now apply it for only in product page

Comment: Not sure about this but what about .catalog-product-view body class that magento use on products page you could inherit CSS properties from it !