# Can you create a background picture in a single static page in M2 (404)?

Tags: magento-2.1, 404-page

I'm wanting to edit my 404 static page content and simply add a background image across the whole viewable pane.

Is there a way to do with in M2.1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the background image by

1. Go to admin ->CMS -> Pages -> 404 Not Found -> Content -> Click Show / Hide editor (Make sure it is html view)

Add a `<div>` to starting and close `</div>` at the end of the content.
Insert image by clicking `insert image...`Then you get something like this `<img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/24.png"}}" alt="" />`. Take this `{{media url="wysiwyg/24.png"}}` only.

Then you can use it as i added.

```
    <div style="background-image: url('{{media url='wysiwyg/7.png'}}');">
       // No route cms content
    </div>
```

> No No @ krishna, i am asking across the whole viewable pane.

Grab the unique calss from 404/No-route page. In my case the class is `cms-no-route`

Create a [style-sheet](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92184/magento-2-how-to-add-custom-css-files-into-the-head-using-helper) and add your styles there.

```
.cms-no-route{
background-image: url("Myiamge.png");
}
```